# How to show detailed storyboard in Game Center?

Tags: ios, swift, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I have incorporated code to login and show game center in my app, but it does not show a detailed storyboard, instead it shows a list item as shown in the screenshot below. When I click on the list item it shows the whole storyboard.
Is there a way to make it detailed i.e showing the score on the first page that the leaderboard opens, instead of the list entry?

[image]

I instead want the screen to look like this,

[image]

Here is the code I am using to show the Game Center,

```
func showLeaderboard() {
var gcViewController: GKGameCenterViewController = GKGameCenterViewController()
gcViewController.gameCenterDelegate = self
gcViewController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerState.Leaderboards
gcViewController.leaderboardIdentifier = "leaderboardid"
self.showViewController(gcViewController, sender: self)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(gcViewController, animated: true)}
```

Comment: please explain, so you want to customize the look of this screen?

Comment: I added how I need it to look